# How can I use flash to divide shape into different smaller parts, such as slicing in photoshop?

Tags: flash, slice

How can I use flash to divide shape into different smaller parts, such as slicing in photoshop?
I need to divide it vertical and horizontally, some parts will be divided in vertical and other parts will be divided horizontally

Comment: I thought you could just use the move tool and drag to create a rectangle to select a part of a shape? Then cut and paste? Does that work. Been a while since I opened Flash.

Comment: I need an automatic way for doing so, just I was doing in photoshop, we were do guidelines then ask photoshop to do slicing for us. can we do this in flash?

Comment: What do you mean by automatic?

Comment: As I explained, I need to make guidelines then do slicing just as doing so in photoshop, can we?

Comment: Nopes cannot be done in Flash as far as I know. You can make guidelines I think but you will have to individually cut out things yourself.